# problem with adc mcp3008 & ads1115

Tags: pi-3, analog-to-digital

My raspberry 3Bs seem to have problems with their I2C and SPI bus.

a. I tried MCP3008 using SPI connected with light sensor and temp sensor, the output on channel 0 &1 is only outputting zeros and 255s.
I've replaced jumper wires 3 times, replaced with another Raspberry pi 3B, replaced with 4 different mcp3008,  replaced light sensor and temp sensors. NOTHING WORKS.

b. Then I tried ADS1115  using I2C connected with temp sensor. I then used adafruit's example simpletest.py following the exact step. Get an erro: 'remote I/O error'

Basically I've replace everything else but my laptop and the software itself(raspbian). Anyone that can help will be very much appreciated.

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

[image: code and result]

[image: ADS1115 result]

Comment: Could you add a diagram to your question? You may use the schematic tool for this. Once your edit space is open, click the schematic icon, or `Ctrl-m` on your keyboard. The diagram will help us help you.

Comment: just updated the images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved.

1. for mcp3008, I was able to get some readings by adding

   spi.max_speed_hz = 1350000

It was giving me certain range of readings although it doesn't seem to read proper sensor readings.

2. for ADS1115, it turns out the pin header connection to sensor is weak. When wired directly to raspi, the problem was solved.

Answer (score 2):

A possible solution that has worked for me was adding the following line after the spi.open() statement:

```
spi.max_speed_hz = 1350000
```

There seems to have been some changes in recent Raspbian Systems, that caused different clock speeds.

Sources:

- https://forum.codesys.com/viewtopic.php?t=8680
- https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=115971

Comment: Thank you. It seemed to work since the numbers are now outputing 1000-1023s, and 850-880s. However, the data doesn't seem to change much when light/ temperature changes.